# Round time to nearest 15 minutes

Tags: excel

I'm trying to round my overtimes in Excel and I found 2 formulas:

```
=FLOOR(A1,"00:15")
```

as well as

```
=ROUNDDOWN((A1)*(24*60/15),0)/(24*60/15)
```

and they both failed when there was a time which does NOT need rounding down.

It is all good when I want to round down e.g. 01:29 to 01:15 or 00:48 to 00:45, but when I have e.g. 01:30 it rounds it down to 01:15, when obviously I need to leave it as it is:/

*A1 is the example cell when my time is stored.*

Comment: If I format the cells as type Time `hh:mm`, both your formulas work fine; 1:30, rounds to 1:30.  I tested this in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

for 01:30, this formula:

```
=FLOOR(A1,"00:15")
```

returns 01:30 for me.

I am on Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, `=FLOOR(A1,"00:15")` should work, but if your version of Excel doesn't do the right thing for some reason, this should work:

`=TIME(HOUR(A1),FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)/15,1)*15,0)`

Answer (score 0):

`=FLOOR(D4*96;1)/96` works fine.
Why 96 ? Because for time units, 1 = 1 day, so 1 hour = 1/24.
You multiply by 24 then by 4 (for quarters), then floor, then divide by 4 to get rounded quarters.

Comment: Care to say what is wrong with the approaches of the OP?